# vim open file in a new tab

Tags: terminal, vim, tabs, editing

I would like to do this -

Open a file, say `a.txt` in vim. Then, do `ctrl+z`, which will take me back to the terminal, and hide vim in background. While I am in the terminal, now I would like to open `b.txt` in a new tab, right next to `a.txt`. Then, I could do `fg` to go back into vim, and have both `a.txt` and `b.txt` opened for me.

Any ideas how this can be done? When I open `b.txt` from the terminal, it launches vim in its own window.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

When inside vim, I use

```
:tabnew filename
```

to open a file in a new tab.

From the terminal, you can do `vim -p filename1 filename2` to open the two files in tabs.

I have added the following lines to my `.vimrc` that allow me to switch between tabs easily.

```
nnoremap <C-Left> :tabprevious<CR>                                                                            
nnoremap <C-Right> :tabnext<CR>
nnoremap <C-j> :tabprevious<CR>                                                                            
nnoremap <C-k> :tabnext<CR>
```

`C` stands for the Ctrl key. Thus, I can do `Ctrl-Right` or `Ctrl-k` to switch  to the next tab, and likewise for the previous.

This works for me.

For those using tmux - I have mapped `Ctrl-h` and `Ctrl-l` for switching windows in tmux. Thus, using the Ctrl key, and h,j,k,l, I am able to switch between all of tmux windows and vim tabs.

EDIT : I did not know this when I asked this question, but you really should avoid tabs to simply manage switching between multiple open files. Use buffers instead. Today, I have

```
nnoremap <C-j> :bprev<CR>                                                                            
nnoremap <C-k> :bnext<CR>
```

Comment: May I know why you recommend buffers rather than tabs, please?

Comment: @icedwater https://stackoverflow.com/a/26710166/2483271

Comment: @NickBull thanks. I prefer split panes myself, I was just exploring tabs at this point. Some kind of justification either way is always helpful.

Comment: As long as it works (and doesn't cause an issue)! You can split buffers too if you ever change your mind https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/76/can-i-open-a-new-vim-split-from-an-existing-buffer

Answer (score 3):

Just open the two files at the same time :

```
vim a.txt b.txt
```

Then use `:b#`  to switch between the tabs.

Comment: this is how to use different buffers, not different tabs.

Answer (score 2):

First, the command for suspending Vim is `<C-z>`, not `<C-x>`.

It doesn't work everywhere but it *could* be possible to do something like this to achieve your goal, **if your Vim is compiled with the `clientserver` feature**:

```
$ vim --remote-tab b.txt
```

See `:help clientserver`.

But…

- You don't *need* to suspend Vim to open another file to edit. You can do that from Vim itself very easily:

  ```
  :e filename
  ```
- Tab pages are not at all equivalent to other editors' tabs. Use buffers instead.